# How to cite Mathematica in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I want to cite mathematica and generate something like following-

Wolfram Research, Inc., Mathematica, Version 8.0, Champaign, IL (2010)

I tried `@misc` this way-

```
@MISC{ram2010,
author={Wolfram Research},
title={Mathematica 8.0},
journal={Wolfram Research Inc.},
address={Champaign, Illinios},
edition={8.0},
year={2010}
}
```

All I could generate was this one-
Wolfarm, R, Mathematica 8.0. 2010

Please help me to write proper command.

Comment: Can I have a minimally working example? (especially interested in the options from your bibliography package).

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is to use BibLaTeX. The BibLaTeX has a `@software` entry type (is similar to `@misc`), and a version field:

```
@software{math,
  author = {{Wolfram Research, Inc.}},
  title = {Mathematica 8.0},
  url = {https://www.wolfram.com},
  version = {0.8},
  date = {2010},
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If found this solution for R ([here](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4759)), which I think is a good solution as well

```
@Manual{ram2010,
    title = {Mathematica 8.0},
    author = {{Wolfram Research Inc.}},
    year = {2010},
    url = {http://www.wolfram.com},
  }
```

Comment: The important bit here, that keeps the author name from being abbreviated are the double {{}}